# Is there an MRI proof of regenerated human intervertebral disc in the spine?

Tags: mri, spine, spinal-cord-compression, posterior-bulging-discs

I have read lots of research reports, surveyed Regenexx, Mesoblast, even seen MRI proof of disc regeneration in animals. However I have yet to see a study where over 20 people benefited (Regenexx does show you before and after but only for some patients ). I have also heard of surgeons in Asia do miracles but again no MRI report.

Please **only** include links to study showing human mri significant improvement

Is there some study from any part of the world which shows this ? I realize it might be in a lab somewhere (even perhaps a secret lab). Would appreciate someone posting some links for that ...

Comment: *I realize it might be in a lab somewhere (even perhaps a secret lab). Would appreciate someone posting some links for that ...* - If anyone had access to a secret lab and was to abuse this power, I doubt that the first thing he or she will do is answer your question.